# Android : Bar graph clickable

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I'm Using `aChartEngine` Library , I am able to plot clickable bar graph. But the method `(getCurrentSeriesAndPoints)`  provided by library returns NULL, when I click on negative values of bar graph. Positive values are clickable , but negative values are not?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the nice tutorial here.

[`Bar Chart in Android With out any Built in jars`](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/).

Here no need of any built in jar files. you can just implement the bar charts custom.try this. I think it may help you

Comment: Thanks for help, but this will not work for me, as i need to plot bar graph on negative as well as positive axis and make both axis clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this issue in SVN. You can checkout the code according to [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/checkout) page and run an `ant dist` in order to build an up to date achartengine.jar file including this fix.

Or you can download an intermediate version [here](http://www.achartengine.org/download/).